# py2exe - Can no longer Copy/Paste text from other Windows app to my Python app after converting my python script to a .EXE file

Tags: python, console, copy-paste, py2exe

I recently tried to convert one of my python scripts (used for file-systems I/O) to a executable file by using py2exe.  However, after successfully generating the .exe file from my python script, I am no longer able to copy and paste any text(or anything for that matter) from other windows apps to my python app console (when I run the script/app from the .exe file). When right click the mouse now, the access window does not pop up any longer.   Does anyone know how I can get around this issue?

Thanks,

A.L.

Answer (score 7):

Right-clicking a console window is a "special feature" of the command line interpreter of Windows Vista and above. It doesn't work on any other command-line tool, so it doesn't longer works for your converted script. You can still access it using the windows menu (small icon in the title bar or Alt+Space).

You could try to get the right-click feature back by messing around with Windows API calls - but the more convenient possibility would be to enable pasting using Ctrl+V and forget about the window menu. A good candidate is [`PyReadline`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline) - install the package and run this at the beginning of your script:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind("control-v: paste")
```