# My script opens a windows cmd prompt, need help pasting into it

Tags: python, windows, cmd, py2exe

I have written a Python program and used py2exe to make it into a windows executable program.

When the program is run it opens a pseudo-cmd window for the user to interact with. (just using print & raw_input)

normally, in a win cmd prompt you can right-click anywhere and hit paste.

But, in THIS pseudo-cmd window you can't. you can right-click on the title bar and go to edit -> paste but thats a pain and most users don't know about it anyway.

I would ~like~ to be able to add this functionality, and/or the ability to ctrl-v to paste directly.

any ideas?

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004772/py2exe-can-no-longer-copy-paste-text-from-other-windows-app-to-my-python-app-a

Comment: ahh, that should help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with msvcrt module(windows only) you can get user input char by char(without 'enter', unlike python's `raw_input`)

```
import msvcrt

def inputemulator():
    buf = []
    while True:
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
        if ch=="\r": #newline
            yield ''.join(buf)
            buf = [] 
        elif ch=="\x03": #ctrl-c
            raise KeyboardInterrupt
        elif ch=="\x16": #ctrl-v, do paste, ...
            pass
        else:
            buf.append(ch)

for line in inputemulator():
    print line
```